# System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render not rendering in @if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this in my cshtml page.

```
<head>
@if (MethodCallThatReturnsBool())
{
    System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/css/bundle");
}
</head>
```

If MethodCallThatReturnsBool returns true, no scripts will be rendered. If I move the Render statement out of the @if block:

```
<head>
@System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/css/bundle");
</head>
```

My bundle's files are listed in the head tag.

Why does the Render call not work inside of an @if block?

Comment: can you please show your controller code where you are setting up `MethodCallThatReturnsBool()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when it works you are replacing the `@System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/css/bundle");` with the text output of this call that is added in the head, so that the browser can parse it and executes the relative request.
When you use the "if" you are in a statement so you have to manually render the output of `@System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/css/bundle");` like this:

```
@if (MethodCallThatReturnsBool())
{
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/css/bundle"));
}
```